# What would make a foxpro memo table loses its records?

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have an old Foxpro database that I work with. The database could be about 100 meg in size and due to corruption and index issue, all of a sudden the new table (table after corruption) is about 4k in size.

I understand that the data is corrupted why would the data disappear though?
If  any Foxpro experts could tell me why is the data missing, i would really appreciate it.

BTW: Foxpro is still very fast compare to a lot of the bells and whistles in databases out there.

The last data truncation/error occurred after a power outage and the data is just gone. The file size decreased to 4k.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe CHR(0) in the corruption, though I wouldn't expect the file to shrink unless you also did something to rewrite the file. Maybe PACK?

Comment: The last error/ truncation occurred after a power outage. Unless this thing constantly rewrite its own data back to disk , i do not get while the data just vanished.

Answer (score 0):

A DBF file has a header followed by data. If the header is corrupted, it loses track of where the data is.

Comment: The header does not know where the data is (that is ok) but why is windows not picking up the file size. Does Microsoft Windows depend on the header to know the file size? Does not quite make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I have had an instances in the past where windows has mis-reported the physical size of a foxpro table, reporting one file to be BIGGER than it actually was and reporting another SMALLER than it actually was.

The data MAY actually still be there, the trick would be getting Foxpro to recognise the fact that there are additional records in the table than recorded in the table header.

QUESTIONS:-

1. Have you packed the table ?
2. have you tried one of the table recovery tools like DBF recovery on the file ?

If the answer is no to both of the above then it maybe worth a try !

Good luck